# Add query to Instagram Redirect (Error: Redirect URI doesn't match original redirect URI)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm using **Laravel Socialite Providers** to use Instagram API. Nonetheless, it should work seamlessly, but still, I get the error, when I try to add an additional query:

> "Error: Redirect URI doesn't match original redirect URI"

---

***What works***

```
return Socialite::driver('instagram')
            ->redirectUrl(config('services.instagram.redirect'))
            ->redirect();
```

***What does not work***

```
return Socialite::driver('instagram')
        ->redirectUrl(config('services.instagram.redirect').'?type=reconnect')
        ->redirect();
```

For my case I just need to add a single query "type=reconnect", but it results to the error.

---

Let's have a look at my URLs:

***What works (url decoded):***

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=somenumber&redirect_uri=https://insta.test/login/instagram/callback&scope=basic&response_type=code&state=BN5XDInTtiRCsSUrHxwB9Ez5wnSDdUDjOmq595v1
```

***What does not work***

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=somenumber&redirect_uri=https://insta.test/login/instagram/callback?type=reconnect&scope=basic&response_type=code&state=bGa5BCb5QN7UPhmOoZThU5fgeLPPSqXik1JdlHkj
```

So how do you add a query?

The doc clearly says you can add the URI like that: ([Doc](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/))

> **REGISTERED REDIRECT URI  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀REDIRECT_URI PARAMETER**
>
> http://yourcallback.com/callback ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀    http://yourcallback.com/callback?type=mobile

Comment: config('services.instagram.redirect') . urlencode('?type=reconnect')

Comment: @Bader So I was excited to see your comment and I tried it, but now I get the error not on my page but on Instagram's site. The URI looks like that: redirect_uri=https://insta.test/login/instagram/callback%253Ftype%253Dreconnect (the https is also there but missing in the comments section)

I even tried to urlencode everything

Comment: @Bader And I think my Url gets automatically encoded. Without using urlencode I get this string: https%3A%2F%2Finsta.test%2Flogin%2Finstagram%2Fcallback%3Ftype%3Dreconnect

Answer (score 1):

So after commenting somethings out, I found out that the URL is correctly encoded and Instagram does let me through the first two steps of the documentation:

1. Direct your user to our authorization URL -> Check
2. Receive the redirect from Instagram -> Check (I got the code)

**But**

3. Request the access_token -> Did not work, because I forgot to set the redirectUrl to the URL of the first step! That means you should set it like that:

   ```
   Socialite::driver('instagram')
        ->redirectUrl(config('services.instagram.redirect').'?type=reconnect')
        ->user();
   ```

Comment: Bingo! I had the same issue, thanks for posting your solution :+1: